# Calling an object's function via a static function

Tags: c++

When might you use such a class:

```
class IteratorFacadeAccess 
{
public:
    template<class Ret, class T>
    static Ret dereference(const T& t) 
    {
        return t.dereference();
    }
};
```

I noticed it in the api I'm working with but I don't understand its purpose.

Comment: You can't "call an object". You can only call a *function*, or a member function.

Comment: You will need to provide more code (how is it used?) to get more insight. The first thing that comes to mind is that someone does not like free functions and decided to create a utility class to wrap what would otherwise be a free function. But there might be an underlying reason for that in the rest of the code... Do types inherit from this? How is the type used?

Comment: Maybe this is done to allow for specializing the deference function for types which do not have the T::deference member function? So we can specialize "static Ret dereference(const T& t)", for when "T" is a pointer, and return "*t" in the body. Thus allowing a consistent signature to all derefernces. [Note:this is highly a guess, and without surrounding code, its hard to guess correctly]

Comment: Could be someone who learned to program with Java or C# and doesn't think of free functions or doesn't know about C++ namespaces.